# Floating Point Exception in C++

Tags: c++, exception, floating-point

I am getting a floating point exception in my code but unable to sort it out. I dnt know what the problem is. Not so good at C++ program and just going through the formulas given.
Please help me:

Program:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int a,b,c,d,ctr,j,Q=1,K=1 ;
    float q0=0.7, p = 0.5 ;
    int phe[3][3];
    double dist[3][3] , mem[3][3],exp[3][3],eplt[3][3], rnd;
    cout<<"enter the iterations, cities , ants ";
    cin>>a>>b>>c;
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            dist[i][j]=(double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
            if (i==j)
            dist[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            cout<< dist[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }

    cout<<"pheromone matrix "<<endl;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            if (i==j)
                phe[i][j]=0;
            else
                phe[i][j]=1;
        }
    }

    for ( i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for ( j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            cout<< phe[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }

    cout<< "after iteration "<<endl;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        ctr=0;
        for (int k=0;k<3;k++)
        {
            // mem[i][k]=(rand()%b)+1;
            // cout<<"memory"<<mem[i][k]<<"\n";
            rnd= (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
            cout<<"hhhhhhh"<<rnd;
            if (rnd<=q0)
            {
                cout<<"Exploitation\n";
                eplt[i][ctr] =(p*phe[i][k])+(Q/K);  
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"EXPLORATION\n";
                eplt[i][ctr]= phe[i][k]/dist[i][k];
            }
            ctr++;
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for (int k=0;k<3;k++)
        {
            cout <<eplt[i][k]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    getch();
}
```

I am getting the error after first loop after "after iteration" completes.
This is the output:

enter the iterations, cities , ants 3
4
4

0       0.003967        0.335154
0.033265        0       0.2172
0.536973        0.195776        0

pheromone matrix
0       1       1
1       0       1
1       1       0

after iteration
hhhhhhh0.949919EXPLORATION
Floating point error: Domain.
Abnormal program termination

Comment: which OS? which compiler? could be helpfull in order to get your debugger started ...

Comment: An annotation apart: are you using phe[i][i] == 0 to set to 0 all the "diagonal" elements? This might not be a good idea, since you would have a 0/0 operation when later calculating eplt: maybe you should consider adding an explicit check before eplt[i][cnt] evaluation (if i==k, eplt = 0, else do the calculation)

Answer (score 5):

At first glance: are you calling the line

```
eplt[i][ctr]= phe[i][k]/dist[i][k];
```

with i = 0 and k = 0 ? From the initialization, dist[0][0] = 0, and you would have a division by zero exception.

Comment: After prinitng "after iteration", we enter the loop and for the first time the formula eplt[i][ctr] =(p*phe[i][k])+(Q/K);  is processed and next time it gives an error..

Comment: You cannot be sure that "Exploitation" is always processed in the first loop, as you have a random value in condition.

Comment: For an added clarity: is it possible that the first time the random extraction sends you in the "Exploitation" branch, while the second time in the "EXPLORATION" one? It seems so from your output, but due to buffering it might not be the case.

Answer (score 3):

I think this line (right after `cout<<"EXPLORATION\n";`:

```
eplt[i][ctr]= phe[i][k]/dist[i][k];
```

is the problem. When i == k, then dist[i][k] == 0.0.

Comment: yes i think i got the error. u are ryt. i will recheck the formula.. thnx for the help. i will provide feedback here if got any other problem related to this.